# Outer join with conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to look up two pieces of metadata (volume and issue) on items which may have either a volume, issue, or both.  The metadata is stored in a table with item ID, key (metadata field ID) and value.

This does work, but it seems overly complex and repetitive:

```
select volume.text_value as volume_value, issue.text_value as issue_value
    from metadatavalue item
    left outer join (select item_id, text_value from metadatavalue
                     where metadata_field_id = 90) volume
                    on item.item_id = volume.item_id
    left outer join (select item_id, text_value from metadatavalue
                     where metadata_field_id = 91) issue
                    on item.item_id = issue.item_id
    where item.metadata_field_id in (90, 91)
```

Is there a simpler way to write this query?

Thanks.

Comment: The query seems to be wrong in the first place, you must use the item ID in the joins !!

Comment: Look mom, no self-joins! Check out my solution below. ;)

Comment: I did use the item ID in the joins.  What I did forget was a DISTINCT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports a full outer join which can simplify the query:

```
  select v.text_value as volume_value, i.text_value as issue_value
      from ( select item_id, text_value
               from metadatavalue
              where metadata_field_id = 90) v
           full join
           ( select item_id, text_value
               from metadatavalue
              where metadata_field_id = 91) i
           using (item_id)
```

Comment: Can't believe it didn't come to my mind instead of these ugly subqueries. This will use an efficient MERGE JOIN, provided there's an index on (metadata_field_id, item_id). Definitely a +1.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and +1.  I'm not that familiar with  PostgresSQL.  I noticed you didn't include item_id in the results but if you wanted item_id you'd have to COALESCE the item_ids from the two tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (item_id)
        item_id,
        CASE metadata_field_id
        WHEN 90 THEN
                text_value
        ELSE    (
                SELECT  text_value
                FROM    metadatavalue m
                WHERE   m.metadata_field_id = 90
                        AND m.item_id = i.item_id
                )
        END AS volume,
        CASE metadata_field_id
        WHEN 91 THEN
                text_value
        ELSE    (
                SELECT  text_value
                FROM    metadatavalue m
                WHERE   m.metadata_field_id = 91
                        AND m.item_id = i.item_id
                )
        END AS issue
FROM    metadatavalue
WHERE   metadata_field_id IN (90, 91)
ORDER BY
        item_id
```

Having an index on `(item_id, metadata_field)` will improve this query.

This will work better if there are few `items` with `metadata` of `90` and `91`, compared to overall number of `items`.

If almost all `items` have these `metadata`, just use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  item_id,
                (
                SELECT  text_value
                FROM    metadatavalue m
                WHERE   m.metadata_field_id = 90
                        AND m.item_id = i.item_id
                ) volume,
                (
                SELECT  text_value
                FROM    metadatavalue m
                WHERE   m.metadata_field_id = 91
                        AND m.item_id = i.item_id
                ) issue
        FROM    items
        ) q
WHERE   issue IS NOT NULL OR volume IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Good point, thanks.  The first query seems to just be a restatement of mine, but better formatted :-)  There are indeed few items with volume/issue.

Comment: @Nicholas: Ummm... I corrected the query a little to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Nicholad: and yet a little, to avoid extra SELECT's where they are not needed.

Comment: I was referring to your pre-edit version.  (The DISTINCT was a red herring, I rewrote the query and didn't test it fully before I posted. Sorry.)  Your new query gives me 'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "volume"' (line 12) though.

Comment: @Nicholas: corrected, forgot an AS before the alias. Nevermind, the FULL OUTER JOIN proposed by @Paul Morgan will be more efficient anyway, provided there's an index on (metadata_field_id, item_id)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select  volume.text_value as volume_value, 
        issue.text_value as issue_value    
from    metadatavalue item    
        left outer join metadatavalue volume                    
            on item.item_id = volume.item_id    
        left outer join metadatavalue issue                    
            on item.item_id = issue.item_id    
where   volume.metadata_field_id = 90
and     issue.metadata_field_id = 91
```

Comment: This doesn't work (it is similar to my original attempt at this query).  It behaves as if the joins were inner joins rather than outer joins.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misinterpretted your question.  "Is there a simpler way to write this query?"  ... I thought it was just a simpler query you wanted.

Comment: @Nicholas: If this is not what you asked, then you need to word your question better.  You asked for simplification of your query and this does that.

Comment: @balabaster: a query that doesn't work is not a simplification, it's just wrong.  (No offense to the answer intended.)  Judging by the correct answers I got, I don't think my question was terribly ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Using the case statement to segregate the values into buckets, the max function will allow the text_value data to float to the top.

```
select
   item_id
  ,max(case metadata_field_id when 90 then text_value else null end) as volume_value
  ,max(case metadata_field_id when 91 then text_value else null end) as issue_value
from
  metadatavalue
group by
   item_id
```

Here's what I used for testing purposes:

```
select
   item_id
  ,max(case metadata_field_id when 90 then text_value else null end) as volume_value
  ,max(case metadata_field_id when 91 then text_value else null end) as issue_value
from
  (
   select 1 as item_id, 90 as metadata_field_id, '90-I am here' as text_value
   union
   select 1 as item_id, 91 as metadata_field_id, '91-Me too' as text_value
   union
   select 2 as item_id, 90 as metadata_field_id, null as text_value
   union
   select 2 as item_id, 91 as metadata_field_id, '91-funky' as text_value
   union
   select 3 as item_id, 90 as metadata_field_id, '90-fresh' as text_value
  ) metadatavalue
group by
   item_id
```

Results:

```
item_id  volume_value  issue_value
1        90-I am here  91-Me too
2        NULL          91-funky
3        90-fresh      NULL
```

*Note: I used SQL Server to model & test and then changed the syntax to match Postgres.*

Answer (score 0):

You can take the predicate out of your inner table into the join condition:

```
select volume.text_value as volume_value, issue.text_value as issue_value
from metadatavalue item
left outer join metadatavalue volume
                on volume.metadata_field_id = 90 and volume.item_id = item.item_id
left outer join metadatavalue issue
                on issue.metadata_field_id = 91 and issue.item_id = item.item_id
where item.metadata_field_id in (90, 91)
```

Although I'm not sure I'm making sense of your schema-- it seems to me that `item` should be referring to a different table than `volume` and `issue`? sth more like:

```
select item.*, volume.text_value as volume_value, issue.text_value as issue_value
from item
left outer join metadatavalue volume
                on volume.metadata_field_id = 90 and volume.item_id = item.item_id
left outer join metadatavalue issue
                on issue.metadata_field_id = 91 and issue.item_id = item.item_id
```

This also makes the rather odd where condition go away. You could put the above query into a view ("item_volume_issue") and it would appear that volume and issue are just additional columns in item_volume_issue instead of separate tables (which is what makes more sense to me).

Comment: The where condition is necessary to limit the query to those items which have a volume or issue.  (Not all items do; I was pretty ambiguous about that in my question, sorry.)